# How to assign value to @State in View from ViewModel?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a movie listing view with basic listing functionality, Once pagination reaches to the last page I want to show an alert for that I am using `reachedLastPage` property.

The `viewModel.state` is an enum, the case movies has associated value in which there is `moreRemaining` property which tells if there are more pages or not.

Once the `moreRemaining` property becomes false I want to make `reachedLastPage` to true so that I can show an alert.

How can I achieve this in best way?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIRefresh

struct MovieListingView<T>: View where T: BaseMoviesListViewModel {
  
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: T
  @State var title: String
  @State var reachedLastPage: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ZStack {
        switch viewModel.state {
        case .loading:
          LoadingView(title: "Loading Movies...")
            .onAppear {
              fetchMovies()
            }
        case .error(let error):
          ErrorView(message: error.localizedDescription, buttonTitle: "Retry") {
            fetchMovies()
          }
        case .noData:
          Text("No data")
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .font(.system(size: 20))
        case .movies(let data):
          List {
            ForEach(data.movies) { movie in
              NavigationLink(destination: LazyView(MovieDetailView(viewModel: MovieDetailViewModel(id: movie.id)))) {
                MovieViewRow(movie: movie)
                  .onAppear {
                    if movie == data.movies.last && data.moreRemaining {
                      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        fetchMovies()
                      }
                    }
                  }
              }
              if movie == data.movies.last && data.moreRemaining {
                HStack {
                  Spacer()
                  ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(data.moreRemaining))
                  Spacer()
                }
              }
            }
          }.pullToRefresh(isShowing: .constant(data.isRefreshing)) {
            print("Refresheeeee")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
              refreshMovies()
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
      .navigationBarTitle("\(title)", displayMode: .inline)
      .alert(isPresented: $reachedLastPage) {
        Alert(title: Text("You have reached to the end of the list."))
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func fetchMovies() {
    viewModel.trigger(.fetchMovies(false))
  }
  
  private func refreshMovies() {
    viewModel.trigger(.fetchMovies(true))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this approach, using `.onReceive(...)`. Add this to your
`ZStack` or `NavigationView`:

```
 .onReceive(Just(viewModel.moreRemaining)) { val in
     reachedLastPage = !val
 }
```

Also add: `import Combine`

Comment: Oh it was that simple 

Comment: Technically, it works, but putting the flag to the view model helps a better separation of concerns (the view doesn't "make decisions", just follows its view model). Not the point of the question, though.

Answer (score -2):

(Ignoring "the best way" part, 'cause it's opinion-based,) one way to achieve that is to make your view model an observable object (which likely already is), adding the publisher of `reachedLastPage` there, and observe it directly from the view. Something like this:

```swift
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var reachedLastPage = false
  init() {
    // Just an example of changing the value.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) { self.reachedLastPage = true }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello World")
      .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.reachedLastPage) {
        Alert(title: Text("Alert is triggered"))
      }
  }
  @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ContentViewModel

  init(viewModel: ContentViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }

}
```

Once `reachedLastPage` takes the `true` value, the alert will be presented.